# How to create html format document without warning when opening it using ms excel?

Tags: excel, apache-poi

Currently our web app need functionality to export data to excel. I am using java program to generate html format document which can be recognized by ms-excel for the sake of simplicity. We did not use any existing framework. 
Below is the sample data that you can save in xxx.html and open in excel.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <td
                    style="background:#CCCCFF;font-weight:bold;font-family:verdana;font-size:85%;width:auto"
                    align="right" NOWRAP="NOWRAP">Id</td>
                <td
                    style="background:#CCCCFF;font-weight:bold;font-family:verdana;font-size:85%;width:auto" NOWRAP="NOWRAP">First Name</td>
                <td
                    style="background:#CCCCFF;font-weight:bold;font-family:verdana;font-size:85%;width:auto" NOWRAP="NOWRAP">Last Name</td>
                <td
                    style="background:#CCCCFF;font-weight:bold;font-family:verdana;font-size:85%;width:auto" NOWRAP="NOWRAP">Email</td>
                <td
                    style="background:#CCCCFF;font-weight:bold;font-family:verdana;font-size:85%;width:auto" NOWRAP="NOWRAP">Department</td>
                <td
                    style="background:#CCCCFF;font-weight:bold;font-family:verdana;font-size:85%;width:auto"
                    align="right" NOWRAP="NOWRAP">Salary</td>
                <td
                    style="background:#CCCCFF;font-weight:bold;font-family:verdana;font-size:85%;width:auto"
                    align="right" NOWRAP="NOWRAP">Start Date</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="font-family:verdana;font-size:80%;width:auto"
                    align="right" NOWRAP="NOWRAP">40</td>
                <td style="font-family:verdana;font-size:80%;width:auto"
                    align="right" NOWRAP="NOWRAP">="Candace"</td>
                <td style="font-family:verdana;font-size:80%;width:auto"
                    align="right" NOWRAP="NOWRAP">="Stevens"</td>
                <td style="font-family:verdana;font-size:80%;width:auto"
                    align="right" NOWRAP="NOWRAP">="cstevens@fakecompany.com"</td>
                <td style="font-family:verdana;font-size:80%;width:auto"
                    align="right" NOWRAP="NOWRAP">="Financial Development"</td>
                <td style="font-family:verdana;font-size:80%;width:auto"
                    align="right" NOWRAP="NOWRAP">85,000.00</td>
                <td style="font-family:verdana;font-size:80%;width:auto"
                    align="right" NOWRAP="NOWRAP">07/13/2003</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

And then I open it with ms-excel 2010, but it prompt warning like below.
**'the file you are trying to open xls is in a different format  '**
[image]

Could someone tell me how to modify the html content so that ms-excel can open it without warning? Since the warning is very annoying and confusing to end-users.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello, is it a web app or client side app ?

Comment: a web app, the back-end is java servlet

Comment: If you have already all data displayed on the page, I would suggest to generate the proper XLSX file on the client side (Search for JavaScript XSLS generation” on google). If you want to keep it server side, I really don’t know with Java, sorry

Comment: On the other note (the question lol), you cannot modify HTML. The warning is mandatory for these kind of files

Comment: I MUST use server side. So you mean the warning can not be dismissed?

Comment: For server side, take a look at this post : http://java67.blogspot.ca/2014/09/how-to-read-write-xlsx-file-in-java-apache-poi-example.html

Comment: Since you've tagged your question with [tag:apache-poi], why not stop messing around with specially-formatted HTML and just generate a true Excel `xls` or `xlsx` file with Apache POI?

Comment: Since it's a very old system. If I can find easy way to fix it , I will not migrate to poi solution.